# Effective word to say destroy regarding student future

Tags: word-usage

I want to convey message regrading destruction of student's future. However, I think destroy can not give effective meaning. I am confused which word is best in following sentence instead of destroy.

*Commercialization of education **destroys** promising and interested student's future as only affluent households can afford higher education.*

Comment: You need to rethink the content of your sentence.  Commercialization (by which I take it you mean for-profit education) may be a bad idea, but it's the cost of all forms of education that hurt the poor.  Promising and interested students come from all socioeconomic classes, and the ones from the upper class won't be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Politicians sometimes speak of young futures being "mortgaged" or even "foreclosed" by various negative factors. This captures the idea of a large burden being attached to the person, or blockages placed in their way. Mortgaged implies that they still keep going, but with a huge cost, where foreclosed suggests more of a complete stop.

Don't use "decimate" - it means to kill one in ten, not to kill 90%.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [compromise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compromise)   or [prejudice](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prejudice):

> - to reduce in quality, value, or degree; weaken or lower: *Don't compromise your standards.*
> - to prejudice unfavourably; weaken: *his behaviour compromised his chances.*
> - to affect detrimentally or harmfully by a judgment or act.

The Free Dictionary

~ *Commercialization of education compromises/prejudices promising and interested student's future as only affluent households can afford higher education.*

Answer (score 0):

**[eviscerates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eviscerate?q=eviscerates)** - Remove the contents of, Deprive (something) of its essential content

**[obliterates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/obliterate)** - Destroy utterly; wipe out, **annihilates** (a good word in of its self)

**[eliminates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eliminate)** - Completely remove or get rid of (something): Exclude (someone or something) from consideration

**[extinguishs](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/extinguish#extinguish__12)** - Put an end to; annihilate, Render **void**

**[voids](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/void#void__10)** An emptiness caused by the loss of something

**[decimates](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/decimate#decimate__2)** - Drastically reduce the strength or effectiveness of; Kill, destroy, or remove a large percentage or part of (historically 90%)

all definitions provided from the oxford dictionary.